# Можно ли сделать окно приложения активным?

Tags: java, desktop

Допустим, у нас есть оконное java-приложение. Пользователь переключился на какое-то другое окно (например, Alt+TAB, или с помощью мыши). Можно ли как-то сделать наше окно активным, т.е. переключиться (по таймеру или как-то еще)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

О, это бедовая тема. По идее, для этого предназначен метод [requestFocus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus%28%29). Однако, с ним есть следующая проблема: это очень платформенно-зависимо и поэтому нет гарантии, что сработает. Например, на Linux с KDE это не производит никакого эффекта.

На эту тему было много рассуждений и есть ряд кривых воркэраундов. Например, такой как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309023/howto-bring-a-java-window-to-the-front). Но это всё очень непереносимо. Например, этот способ у меня тоже не работает. Это потому, что window manager отклоняет все попытки сделать что-то такое. По ходу, я вообще не видел, чтобы хоть какое-то окно высплывало (кроме notification-ов, которые always on top).

Comment: И это правильно. KDE заботится о пользователе. Меня лично бесит, когда какое-то приложение думает, что оно тут самое главное и суёт мне под нос свои окна. Помигай тихонько в панели — я тебя увижу.

Comment: Хмм, понятно. Я не хочу навязывать себя постоянно. Сделать приложение активным хотелось бы через некоторое время (есть определенное событие) после того, как я передал управление другому приложению с помощью класса Desktop. То есть я сам открыл другое приложение, и теперь хочу вернуть пользователя обратно.

Comment: @kirelagin, отличная идея! А вы знаете, как заставить java-приложение помигать в панели? Попробую найти информацию об этом.